# PyQt New Style Signals & Slots - Can't pass parameters

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, signals-slots

In the old style signals and Slots I am able to pass my own parameters to the handler like this. (In this case I am passing a Widget and a reference to self)

```
obj.connect(form.tableScores,QtCore.SIGNAL("itemChanged(QTableWidgetItem*)"),lambda: itemChanged(form,obj))
```

The only down side is that I loose the QTableWidgetItem data, but I am able to get this through the widget reference in the form parameter. The key thing is that I need access to obj which this method gives me.

But in the new style I get an error.

```
form.tableScores.itemChanged.connect(itemChanged(form,obj))
```

I seem to be limited to this format

```
form.tableScores.itemChanged.connect(itemChanged)
```

Is there a way that I can pass my own parameters in new style Signals and Slots and ideally also retain a reference to QTableWidgetItem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use *functools* module

example:

```
import functools
```

Then you can use your parameters with:

```
form.tableScores.itemChanged.connect(functools.partial(itemChanged, param1, param2, param3, [...]))
```